# Стиль для блока с изображениями

Tags: php, css

Ниже приведён код вывода превью изображений, изображения выводятся горизонтально в одну линию, никак не могу добиться, чтобы когда количество превью превышает ширину блока, появлялась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

```
 <style type="text/css"> 
 .images{position:relative; float:left}
 </style>
```

и

```
 <?php if (isset($filenames)) : ?>
 <?php foreach ($filenames as $k => $filename) : ?>
   <div id="images">
     <img src="<?php echo HOST . 'imagesCatalog/' . $filename ?>" 
      alt="" id="photo_mini_<?php echo $k ?>"class="photo_mini" />
   </div>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 <?php endif ?>
```

**Добавлено.**

Вот пробовал так, но изображения переносятся на другую строку и появляется вертикальная прокрутка:

```
<div style="width:1024px;height:130px;overflow-x:scroll ">

<?php if (isset($filenames)) : ?>
<?php foreach ($filenames as $k => $filename) : ?>
    <div style="position:relative;float:left; height:130px;white-space: no-wrap "> 
      <img src="<?php echo HOST . 'imagesCatalog/' . $filename ?>" 
          alt="" id="photo_mini_<?php echo $k ?>" class="photo_mini" />
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>

</div>
```

Comment: попробуйте убрать 'float: left'. в плавающей модели элементы извлекаются из нормальной модели...это и может вызывать проблемы...

Comment: Какие ещё могут быть варианты, потому как решение не найдено

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="imagesStripe" style="overflow-x: scroll; white-space: no-wrap;"></div>
```

Меня, конечно, убъют за overflow-x, но без него вряд ли выйдет что-то сделать

Comment: Может, стоит складывать все в контейнер какой-то?

Comment: Да уже всё перепробовал, ни фига не получается...

Comment: Мне кажется, можно обойтись и без `scroll-x`, так как `no-wrap` и так добавит прокрутку горизонтальную.

Comment: не пробывали пользоваться display: inline-block вместо float: left?

Comment: Пробовал, ничего не получаятся. Я так подозреваю, что для решения этой задачи нужно скрипт прописывать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать `width` и `display:block;` для картинок

Answer (score 0):

указать `width:auto;` контейнеру не пробвали?